# Ruby on Rails Class Variable not being referenced by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small web app in Ruby on Rails which lists antique documents and the locations that are referenced by the documents. I can update locations that are already attached to documents, but when trying to create a new document, I get the following error

```
undefined method `locations' for nil:NilClass
```

The NilClass occurs in LocationController#new:

```
def new
  @location = @document.locations.new
end
```

This is called from the view as such

```
<%= form_for(@location,:url=>new_document_location_path(@document)) do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => "document_locations/form", :locals =>{:f=>f} %>
  <%= f.submit "Save",:class=>"span2 btn" %>
<%end%>
```

So for some reason, the @document class isn't being referenced by the controller.   I know the class is accessible to the view and in scope as I am able to view document attributes within the form (eg <%= @document.id %>

So, why is the Controller not able to reference the @document variable?  I'm assuming this is down to how I am passing the class variable.  Eitherway, I'd be very grateful for some pointers.

This is how the models are defined

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
end
```

Here's my routes

```
Pastpaper::Application.routes.draw do

  # added in to test
  match '/documents/:id/locations/create' => 'locations#create'
  resources :documents do 
    collection do 
      match 'permanent_delete/:id' => 'documents#permanently_delete',:as => :permanent_delete
    end

    match '/authorinfo' => 'documents#authorinfo',:as => :authorinfo

    match '/publicationinfo' => 'documents#publicationinfo',:as => :publicationinfo
    match '/images' => 'documents#itemimages' ,:as => :itemimages
    match '/locations' => 'documents#locations',:as => :locations
    match '/itempeople'  => 'documents#itempeople' ,:as => :itempeople
    match '/people_facts_locations' => 'documents#people_facts_locations',:as => :people_facts_loc
    resources :locations, :controller=>"locations"
    resources :people ,:controller => "document_people"
    resources :document_facts
    resource :facts
    resources :document_photos
  end

  resources :home do 
    collection do
      get 'document_search','simple_location_search','date_search','simple_people_search','simple_organisation_search','document_filter'
      get 'search_results'
      post 'search_results'
    end
  end

  match 'documents/publicationinfo/:id' => 'documents#publicationinfo',:as => :publicationinfo
  match 'documents/update/publishinginfo/:id' => 'documents#publishinginfo',:as => :publishinginfo 
  match 'documents/document_image_remove/:id' => 'documents#remove_image',:as=>"remove_image"
  match 'documents/make_primary_image/:id' => 'documents#make_primary_image',:as => :make_primary_image
  match 'person_detail/:id' => 'documents#person_detail',:as=>'person_detail'

  match 'about', :to=> 'pages#about'
  match 'contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match 'privacy', :to => 'pages#privacy'
  match 'terms', :to => 'pages#terms'
  match 'help', :to => 'pages#help'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :document_types
    resources :statuses
    resources :attribute_types
    resources :event_types
    resources :users
    resources :orders
    resources :documents
    match 'restore_document/:id' => 'Documents#restore_document', :as => 'restore_document'
    match 'report' => 'report#index' ,:as=>:report
    match 'report/surname_report' => 'report#surname_report',:as=>:surname_report
    match 'report/location_report' => 'report#location_report',:as=>:location_report
  end
  root :to => 'home#index'

end
```

And here's the relevant Controllers:
DocumentController

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prepare_document ,:only => [:locations]

  def locations
    @locations = @document.locations.order("id asc")
    @location = @document.locations.new
  end

private
  def prepare_document
    if params[:id]
      @document = Document.find(params[:id], :include => [:document_attributes])
    elsif params[:document_id]
      @document = Document.find(params[:document_id], :include => [:document_attributes])
    end  
  end
end
```

LocationsController

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :prepare_document

  def new
    @location = @document.locations.new
  end

  def create
    @location = @document.locations.build
    if @location.save
      redirect_to document_locations_url(@document)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @location = @document.locations.find(params[:id])
    if @location.update_attributes(params[:location])
      redirect_to document_locations_url(@document)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def prepare_document
    if params[:document_id]
      if current_user.is_admin?
        @document = Document.find(params[:document_id], :include => [:document_attributes])
      else
        @document = current_user.documents.find(params[:document_id], :include => [:document_attributes])
      end  
    end  
  end
end
```

This is how my routes rake out

```
                           logout GET    /logout(.:format)                                          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
                            login POST   /login(.:format)                                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
                  forgot_password        /forgot_password(.:format)                                 {:action=>"new", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                        user_home GET    /profile(.:format)                                         {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                deactivateaccount        /account/deactivate(.:format)                              {:controller=>"users", :action=>"accountdeactivate"}
                   changepassword        /account/changepassword(.:format)                          {:controller=>"users", :action=>"changepassword"}
                         register        /user/registration(.:format)                               {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
                            users GET    /users(.:format)                                           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                                  POST   /users(.:format)                                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
                        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                  password_resets GET    /password_resets(.:format)                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                                  POST   /password_resets(.:format)                                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"password_resets"}
               new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)                             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"password_resets"}
              edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                   password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                                  PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"password_resets"}
                                  DELETE /password_resets/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"password_resets"}
              password_reset_path        /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:controller=>"password_resets", :action=>"edit"}
                                         /documents/:id/locations/create(.:format)                  {:controller=>"locations", :action=>"create"}
       permanent_delete_documents        /documents/permanent_delete/:id(.:format)                  {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"permanently_delete"}
              document_authorinfo        /documents/:document_id/authorinfo(.:format)               {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"authorinfo"}
         document_publicationinfo        /documents/:document_id/publicationinfo(.:format)          {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"publicationinfo"}
              document_itemimages        /documents/:document_id/images(.:format)                   {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"itemimages"}
               document_locations        /documents/:document_id/locations(.:format)                {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"locations"}
              document_itempeople        /documents/:document_id/itempeople(.:format)               {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"itempeople"}
        document_people_facts_loc        /documents/:document_id/people_facts_locations(.:format)   {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"people_facts_locations"}
                                  GET    /documents/:document_id/locations(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"locations"}
                                  POST   /documents/:document_id/locations(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"locations"}
            new_document_location GET    /documents/:document_id/locations/new(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"locations"}
           edit_document_location GET    /documents/:document_id/locations/:id/edit(.:format)       {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"locations"}
                document_location GET    /documents/:document_id/locations/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:document_id/locations/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"update", :controller=>"locations"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:document_id/locations/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"locations"}
                  document_people GET    /documents/:document_id/people(.:format)                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"document_people"}
                                  POST   /documents/:document_id/people(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"document_people"}
              new_document_person GET    /documents/:document_id/people/new(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"document_people"}
             edit_document_person GET    /documents/:document_id/people/:id/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"document_people"}
                  document_person GET    /documents/:document_id/people/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"show", :controller=>"document_people"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:document_id/people/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"document_people"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:document_id/people/:id(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"document_people"}
          document_document_facts GET    /documents/:document_id/document_facts(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"document_facts"}
                                  POST   /documents/:document_id/document_facts(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"document_facts"}
       new_document_document_fact GET    /documents/:document_id/document_facts/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"document_facts"}
      edit_document_document_fact GET    /documents/:document_id/document_facts/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"document_facts"}
           document_document_fact GET    /documents/:document_id/document_facts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"document_facts"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:document_id/document_facts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"document_facts"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:document_id/document_facts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"document_facts"}
                   document_facts POST   /documents/:document_id/facts(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"facts"}
               new_document_facts GET    /documents/:document_id/facts/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"facts"}
              edit_document_facts GET    /documents/:document_id/facts/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"facts"}
                                  GET    /documents/:document_id/facts(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"facts"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:document_id/facts(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"facts"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:document_id/facts(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"facts"}
         document_document_photos GET    /documents/:document_id/document_photos(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"document_photos"}
                                  POST   /documents/:document_id/document_photos(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"document_photos"}
      new_document_document_photo GET    /documents/:document_id/document_photos/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"document_photos"}
     edit_document_document_photo GET    /documents/:document_id/document_photos/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"document_photos"}
          document_document_photo GET    /documents/:document_id/document_photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"document_photos"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:document_id/document_photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"document_photos"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:document_id/document_photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"document_photos"}
                        documents GET    /documents(.:format)                                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"documents"}
                                  POST   /documents(.:format)                                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"documents"}
                     new_document GET    /documents/new(.:format)                                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"documents"}
                    edit_document GET    /documents/:id/edit(.:format)                              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"documents"}
                         document GET    /documents/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"documents"}
                                  PUT    /documents/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"documents"}
                                  DELETE /documents/:id(.:format)                                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"documents"}
                    paypal_cancel        /payments/cancel(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"payments", :action=>"paypal_cancel"}
                    paypal_return        /payments/success(.:format)                                {:controller=>"payments", :action=>"paypal_return"}
                       paypal_ipn        /payments/ipn(.:format)                                    {:controller=>"payments", :action=>"create"}
       document_search_home_index GET    /home/document_search(.:format)                            {:action=>"document_search", :controller=>"home"}
simple_location_search_home_index GET    /home/simple_location_search(.:format)                     {:action=>"simple_location_search", :controller=>"home"}
           date_search_home_index GET    /home/date_search(.:format)                                {:action=>"date_search", :controller=>"home"}
  simple_people_search_home_index GET    /home/simple_people_search(.:format)                       {:action=>"simple_people_search", :controller=>"home"}
simple_organisation_search_home_index GET    /home/simple_organisation_search(.:format)                 {:action=>"simple_organisation_search", :controller=>"home"}
       document_filter_home_index GET    /home/document_filter(.:format)                            {:action=>"document_filter", :controller=>"home"}
        search_results_home_index GET    /home/search_results(.:format)                             {:action=>"search_results", :controller=>"home"}
                                  POST   /home/search_results(.:format)                             {:action=>"search_results", :controller=>"home"}
                       home_index GET    /home(.:format)                                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
                                  POST   /home(.:format)                                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"home"}
                         new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"home"}
                        edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)                                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"home"}
                             home GET    /home/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"home"}
                                  PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"home"}
                                  DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                                        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"home"}
                  publicationinfo        /documents/publicationinfo/:id(.:format)                   {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"publicationinfo"}
                   publishinginfo        /documents/update/publishinginfo/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"publishinginfo"}
                     remove_image        /documents/document_image_remove/:id(.:format)             {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"remove_image"}
               make_primary_image        /documents/make_primary_image/:id(.:format)                {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"make_primary_image"}
                    person_detail        /person_detail/:id(.:format)                               {:controller=>"documents", :action=>"person_detail"}
                            about        /about(.:format)                                           {:action=>"about", :controller=>"pages"}
                          contact        /contact(.:format)                                         {:action=>"contact", :controller=>"pages"}
                          privacy        /privacy(.:format)                                         {:action=>"privacy", :controller=>"pages"}
                            terms        /terms(.:format)                                           {:action=>"terms", :controller=>"pages"}
                             help        /help(.:format)                                            {:action=>"help", :controller=>"pages"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def new
  @location = @document.locations.build
end
```

Use build not new. And make your prepare_document private in your controller.

Also

```
<%= form_for([@document, @location]) do |f| %>
```

Your url parameter was wrong, you shouldn't post forms to the new action, you should post them to the update action like I showed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've followed your recommendations.  By changing the new action to use build, I am still getting the 'Unknown Method' error.  I have changed the call to as above without the url, and although that now doesn't error, it also doesn't save - So which action would that be using?  I have also tried `form_for ([@document, @location])` with a url parameter, but that still returns the NilClass error.

Comment: Don't use :url option in form_for, you don't need it. It should go to create action. I don't see that you have a create action, that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks, there is now a create action (added to the original question), but it does not seem to be being touched.  Presumably a routing problem?  I have location set as a resource so it should automatically produce a create route, I believe?    That does not seem to be the case.  I have added the output of rake routes, too.

Comment: I don't see a create action in your rake routes. Also look in server log what's being called.

Comment: You are correct - but I don't know why there's no create action in the routes.  Shouldn't `resources locations` create this automatically?

Comment: Yes. There should be a POST route to /documents/:document_id/locations. Restart server. Show your routes.rb and full rake routes.

Comment: I've updated the original question with full routes.rb and rake routes (I've removed the obviously irrelevant stuff as I was dangerously over my word count).  This definitely seems to be a routing problem as when I move `resources :locations, :controller=>"locations"` above `match '/locations' => 'documents#locations',:as => :locations`, a new location is created as soon as I view a document (but I can't see the actual document page!).

Comment: Don't use match routes unless you are on advanced rails level. People always screw things up with match routes because they don't understand the Rails routing system. __Always__ avoid match routes. So first of all remove all match routes and also remove :controller=>"locations". After you remove __all__ match routes then if it still doesn't work let me know.

Comment: The issue is with match '/locations' => 'documents#locations',:as => :locations Like I said don't use match routes until you are on advanced rails level, the only ones that are okay to use is the ones you use for about etc. on pages controller. Remove everything else and use restful routes and avoid match. As long as you keep adding match routes without understanding fully the routing you will have problems like this.

Comment: I think you are right.  The site was built for my by developers who appear to have neither known nor cared what they were doing and everything is just rushed and hacked together.  Even simple changes just breaks everything so I'm trying to reengineer areas to make it more RESTful, but I'm new to this and have a lot to learn...I appreciate your help.

Comment: With a combination of the route changes and the changes you suggested above this now works.  You are my hero. I will accept your original answer.